# Problem with JavaFX, EclipseLink and javax.persistence

Tags: java, javafx, eclipselink, jpa

I'm trying to write a program with *JavaFX* that can interact with a MySQL database.
I already wrote the code to interact with the database and it is working.
I used the libraries `EclipseLink` and `jakarta.persistence(2.2.3)` and `mysql-connector(8.0.20)`.
But as soon as I use these three libraries in a JavaFX project I get an error message.

```
java: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Modules java.persistence and eclipselink export package javax.persistence.criteria to module mysql.connector.java
```

I tried different versions of the libraries and import them directly as a `.jar` and with Maven.

That is my pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>das</groupId>
    <artifactId>sad</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>sad</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <junit.version>5.7.1</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>14.0.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>14.0.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
            <version>11.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.dlsc.formsfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>formsfx-core</artifactId>
            <version>11.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kordamp.bootstrapfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrapfx-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>14</source>
                    <target>14</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>das.sad/das.sad.HelloApplication</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And that my module-info.java

```java
module das.sad {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;

    requires org.controlsfx.controls;
    requires com.dlsc.formsfx;
    requires org.kordamp.bootstrapfx.core;
    requires java.persistence;
    requires mysql.connector.java;
    requires eclipselink;

    opens das.sad to javafx.fxml;
    exports das.sad;
}
```

I use the *IntelliJ IDE* and auto-generated the *pom.xml* and the *module-info.java.*

Comment: See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=525457 for details, but check which version of EclipseLink you are using as the later ones may help.